# 'int' object has no attribute 'lower' while doing tokenizer.fit_on_text(d['column_name'])

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, tokenize

```
tokenizer=Tokenizer(num_words=1000, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(d['column'].values)

x=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(d['column'].values)
```

In column POS_words I have all sentences having skills (C#, Office365, ...) there are some nos. +91.

I want to convert it into array but its throwing error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a59a11ef92f5> in <module>()
      1 tokenizer=Tokenizer(num_words=1000, split=' ')
----> 2 tokenizer.fit_on_texts(d['POS_words'].values)
      3 
      4 x=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(d['POS_words'].values)
      5 #xtest=tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test['POS_words'].values)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/text.py in text_to_word_sequence(text, filters, lower, split)
     41     """
     42     if lower:
---> 43         text = text.lower()
     44 
     45     if sys.version_info < (3,):

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Please tell me how to fix this

Comment: There is an int in `d['POS_words']` they need to be strings. You cannot `lower()` and int: `[s.lower() for s in ['test', 5]]`

Comment: Do you have an example input and output? This will make it easier to understand what you want to do.

Comment: @BernardoTrindade I am training my data using LSTM which is why i need the nos. in the sentences. If I want to detect skills I need to have Office365 and (+91 not a skill)

Comment: @It_is_Chris I don't understand what you are trying to say. I cannot remove that int yesterday it was working fine I was able to train but all of sudden today  when I tried to run this command this is the error i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved

```
d['column']=d['column'].astype(str)
```